# My fired GWT event is not handled by the parent presenter

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform, event-bus

I have a child presenter (added to the parent in a slot) that fires an event through the `eventBus` (on a condition) when `onBind()` is called :

```
class ChildPresenter extends PresenterWidget<?> {

        void onBind() {

               instance = initMyInstance();

               if (instance == null) {
                        eventBus.fireEvent(new MyEvent());
               }
        }

       //...
}
```

On the parent, i handle the event in the `onBind()` method like this :

```
class ParentPresenter extends Presenter<..>{

     void onBind() {

           eventBus.addHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, new MyEventHandler() {...} );
     }
}
```

I tried also this in the parent: `addRegisteredHandler(LoggedOutEvent.TYPE, this)` and  `addVisibleHandler(...)` too, where i implement the `MyEventHandler` interface in the parent presenter but it does not handle the fired event.

Am i doing it wrong? I noticed also when i move the handling process to the `onReveal()` method of my parent presenter, it worked but twice!!

Comment: what are you trying achieve though `onBind` method? This method call only once while initialize presenter, than it will not call.

Comment: Handlers should be added in onBind() method. It was a timing issue. The child presenter fired the event before the parent adds a Handler for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have a timing issue. Make sure that addHandler() in the parent is called before fire in the child, and also I think it should happened in a separate browser event. Try this to see if it helps:

```
class ChildPresenter extends PresenterWidget<?> {

        void onBind() {

               instance = initMyInstance();

               if (instance == null) {
                   Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

                       @Override
                       public void execute() {
                            eventBus.fireEvent(new MyEvent());
                       }
                   });

               }
        }

       //...
}
```